# How to add OCAMLOPTFLAGS to Oasis?

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I would like to add few flags (S, inline 20, nodynlink) to my _oasis file but I get a compilation error:

```
AlphaFeatures: ocamlbuild_more_args
XOCamlbuildExtraArgs: "-cflags '-S -inline 20'"
```

I am wondering how can you add these.

The rather long error:

```
node:dir user$ make
ocaml setup.ml -build
/Users/user/.opam/system/bin/ocamlbuild: unknown option '-inline'.
Usage /Users/user/.opam/system/bin/ocamlbuild [options] <target>
  -version                    Display the version
  --version                   same as -version
  -vnum                       Display the version number
  --vnum                      same as -vnum
  -quiet                      Make as quiet as possible
  -verbose <level>            Set the verbosity level on a scale from 0 to 8 (included)
  -documentation              Show rules and flags
  -log <file>                 Set log file
  -no-log                     No log file
  -clean                      Remove build directory and other files, then exit
  -r                          Traverse directories by default (true: traverse)
  -I <path>                   Add to include directories
  -Is <path,...>              (same as above, but accepts a (comma or blank)-separated list)
  -X <path>                   Directory to ignore
  -Xs <path,...>              (idem)
  -lib <flag>                 Link to this ocaml library
  -libs <flag,...>            (idem)
  -mod <module>               Link to this ocaml module
  -mods <module,...>          (idem)
  -pkg <package>              Link to this ocaml findlib package
  -pkgs <package,...>         (idem)
  -package <package>          (idem)
  -syntax <syntax>            Specify syntax using ocamlfind
  -lflag <flag>               Add to ocamlc link flags
  -lflags <flag,...>          (idem)
  -cflag <flag>               Add to ocamlc compile flags
  -cflags <flag,...>          (idem)
  -docflag <flag>             Add to ocamldoc flags
  -docflags <flag,...>        (idem)
  -yaccflag <flag>            Add to ocamlyacc flags
  -yaccflags <flag,...>       (idem)
  -lexflag <flag>             Add to ocamllex flags
  -lexflags <flag,...>        (idem)
  -ppflag <flag>              Add to ocaml preprocessing flags
  -pp <flag,...>              (idem)
  -tag <tag>                  Add to default tags
  -tags <tag,...>             (idem)
  -plugin-tag <tag>           Use this tag when compiling the myocamlbuild.ml plugin
  -plugin-tags <tag,...>      (idem)
  -tag-line <tag>             Use this line of tags (as in _tags)
  -show-tags <path>           Show tags that applies on that pathname
  -ignore <module,...>        Don't try to build these modules
  -no-links                   Don't make links of produced final targets
  -no-skip                    Don't skip modules that are requested by ocamldep but cannot be built
  -no-hygiene                 Don't apply sanity-check rules
  -no-plugin                  Don't build myocamlbuild.ml
  -no-stdlib                  Don't ignore stdlib modules
  -dont-catch-errors          Don't catch and display exceptions (useful to display the call stack)
  -just-plugin                Just build myocamlbuild.ml
  -byte-plugin                Don't use a native plugin but bytecode
  -plugin-option              Use the option only when plugin is run
  -sanitization-script        Change the file name for the generated sanitization script
  -no-sanitize                Do not generate sanitization script
  -nothing-should-be-rebuilt  Fail if something needs to be rebuilt
  -classic-display            Display executed commands the old-fashioned way
  -use-menhir                 Use menhir instead of ocamlyacc
  -use-jocaml                 Use jocaml compilers instead of ocaml ones
  -use-ocamlfind              Use the 'ocamlfind' wrapper instead of using Findlib directly to determine command-line arguments. Use -no-ocamlfind to disable. Implies -plugin-use-ocamlfind.
  -no-ocamlfind               Don't use ocamlfind. Implies -plugin-no-ocamlfind.
  -plugin-use-ocamlfind       Use the 'ocamlfind' wrapper for building myocamlbuild.ml
  -plugin-no-ocamlfind        Don't use ocamlfind for building myocamlbuild.ml
  -toolchain <toolchain>      Set the Findlib toolchain to use. The default toolchain is always used for building myocamlbuild.ml.
  -j <N>                      Allow N jobs at once (0 for unlimited)
  -build-dir <path>           Set build directory (implies no-links)
  -install-lib-dir <path>     Set the install library directory
  -install-bin-dir <path>     Set the install binary directory
  -where                      Display the install library directory
  -which <command>            Display path to the tool command
  -ocamlc <command>           Set the OCaml bytecode compiler
  -plugin-ocamlc <command>    Set the OCaml bytecode compiler used when building myocamlbuild.ml (only)
  -ocamlopt <command>         Set the OCaml native compiler
  -plugin-ocamlopt <command>  Set the OCaml native compiler used when building myocamlbuild.ml (only)
  -ocamldep <command>         Set the OCaml dependency tool
  -ocamldoc <command>         Set the OCaml documentation generator
  -ocamlyacc <command>        Set the ocamlyacc tool
  -menhir <command>           Set the menhir tool (use it after -use-menhir)
  -ocamllex <command>         Set the ocamllex tool
  -ocamlmklib <command>       Set the ocamlmklib tool
  -ocamlmktop <command>       Set the ocamlmktop tool
  -ocamlrun <command>         Set the ocamlrun tool
  --                          Stop argument processing, remaining arguments are given to the user program
  -help                       Display this list of options
  --help                      Display this list of options

E: Failure("Command ''/Users/user/.opam/system/bin/ocamlbuild' src/main.native -cflags -S -inline 20 -tag debug' terminated with error code 1")
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: What kind of compilation error do you get?

Comment: Hi @ÉtienneMillon I have added the error.

Comment: Great! That should help you find an anwser :)

Answer (score 2):

The `-cflags` option takes a comma-separated list of options and passes it to the `ocamlc` compiler. So, in `ocamlbuild' src/main.native -cflags -S -inline 20` only the `-S` option is passed to `ocamlc`, while `-inline` and `20` are taken by `ocamlbuild` itself. So, the right way to pass multiple options to `ocamlc` is:

```
ocamlbuild -cflags -S,-inline,20 x.byte
```

This will also fail, though, since `ocamlc` doesn't recognize `-cflags` or `-inline` options, as they are options of `ocamlopt`. OCaml has two compiler - one is called `ocamlc` and it produces the bytecode, another is `ocamlopt` that produces the native code. Though they have a few common options, some are definitely not shared. For example, the bytecode compiler can't emit assembly.

To pass options to `ocamlopt` you can either use the `NativeOpt` field in `_oasis` or use parametric tags in the `_tags` file (the latter is useful for controlling flambda). Look at `ocamlbuild -documentation` for the actual set of recognized tags.